# Specify Spotlight keywords iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, spotlight

In iOS 9, is there a way to give spotlight a list of keywords by which users can search for a specific app?

Example scenario: *App Title (as displayed on spring board): "Photos," but User searches for "Pictures" or "Photographs."*

If not, are the keywords as listed in the App Store used index the app on the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoreSpotlight Framework does it.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CoreSpotlight_Framework/
- https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios9-day-by-day-day1-search-apis

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using either `NSUserActivity` or `Core Spotlight framework`.

`Keywords` property of `NSUserActivity`  class can be used.
                         OR
In Core Spotlight framework, `keywords` property of `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` can be used.