# iOS app: keep old application name as keyword?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I need to rename my application's name.

Is it possible to store some metadata of its old name somewhere? 
Users may try to search its old name in the iPhone's search option.

Is there any designated value in the plist file or elsewhere so that its bundle display name is the new name, while the old name is still searchable?

Comment: you can add asmany keywords as you want in the itunes connect.

Comment: By adding old and new names as keywords, user will be able to search the app by old name as well. There is no other shortcut or plist entry method.

Comment: Keywords aren't accessible to the iPhone's search ("spotlight search").

Comment: before ios10 spotlight search will not entertain your old app name.Its by design.You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799748/specify-spotlight-keywords-ios-9 for ios9.

Comment: You can achieve using spotlight search

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @MohammedShakeer can you add an answer to use NSUserDefaults for iOS 9 and iTunesConnect keywords for iOS 10 and I'll mark it as the right answer?

Comment: @Droppy you are a trigger happy. Please undo you vote.

Comment: @Nili: Issue resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this your application has to be launched atleast once, and in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of your `AppDelegate` you can index your `Core Spotlight` searchable item like below:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet* attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:@"myApp.image"];

attributeSet.title = @"My Old App";
attributeSet.contentDescription = @"This application help you in acheiving so & so";
CSSearchableItem *item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc] initWithUniqueIdentifier:@"myApp" domainIdentifier:@"com.myapp" attributeSet:attributeSet];
// Index the item.
[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex] indexSearchableItems:@[item] completionHandler: ^(NSError * __nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Search item indexed");
}];
```

You can even add thumbnail image to be shown when the app with old name is searched; You need to add following code before creating the `searchableItem`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MercC"];
NSData *thumbNailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
attributeSet.thumbnailData = thumbNailData;
```